# Как перебрать объект типа list с двойными индексами?

Tags: python, list

Как можно циклом или чем-то еще этот код сделать короче? Пытаюсь распарсить список типа: [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]].

```
        reader[0][0] = self.a
        reader[0][1] = self.b
        reader[0][2] = self.c
        reader[0][3] = self.d

        reader[1][0] = self.a
        reader[1][1] = self.b
        reader[1][2] = self.c
        reader[1][3] = self.d         
        
        reader[2][0] = self.a
        reader[2][1] = self.b
        reader[2][2] = self.c
        reader[2][3] = self.d

        reader[3][0] = self.a
        reader[3][1] = self.b
        reader[3][2] = self.c
        reader[3][3] = self.d
```

Comment: Организуйте поля self в список. Сделайте цикл по первому измерению reader и копируйте тот список в reader[i]

Comment: reader = [[self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d] for _ in range(4)]

Answer (score 0):

```
for idx1 in reader:
    for item in idx1:
        # ваш код (чтобы использовать цифру, например 3, используйте переменную item)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).